# Implementation of Floor Casting Producing Unexpected Errors

Tags: java, c++, indexoutofboundsexception, raycasting, texture-mapping

I have been following and translating a YouTube tutorial about how to create a raycasting engine as the person who made the video created theirs in C++ and I am making mine in Java.

Link To The Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PC1RaETIx3Y

For the most part, following the creator's tutorial has turned out exactly as it is supposed to be. However when I try to implement the floor casting that they used I constantly get the following error:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxF27.png

Following the stack trace, it says that it has an error with I try to get the color value from the map position of the floor and ceiling arrays:

```
int mpF = mapF[(int)(texY/32.0)*mapX+(int)(texX/32.0)]*32*32;
int mpC = mapC[(int)(texY/32.0)*mapX+(int)(texX/32.0)]*32*32;
```

I have tried implementing other solutions to floor casting but I have a hard time grasping what it is doing and those solutions don't fit the engine that I am building. I was wondering if anyone knows what could be wrong with my implementation as my calculations should be functionally the same as the creator's. I would also accept answers that provide a different solution that makes use of how the engine is implemeted.

Their Code:

```
 for(y=lineOff+lineH;y<320;y++)
 {
  float dy=y-(320/2.0), deg=degToRad(ra), raFix=cos(degToRad(FixAng(pa-ra)));
  tx=px/2 + cos(deg)*158*32/dy/raFix;
  ty=py/2 - sin(deg)*158*32/dy/raFix;
  int mp=mapF[(int)(ty/32.0)*mapX+(int)(tx/32.0)]*32*32;
  float c=All_Textures[((int)(ty)&31)*32 + ((int)(tx)&31)+mp]*0.7;
  glColor3f(c/1.3,c/1.3,c);glPointSize(8);glBegin(GL_POINTS);glVertex2i(r*8+530,y);glEnd();

  mp=mapC[(int)(ty/32.0)*mapX+(int)(tx/32.0)]*32*32;
  c=All_Textures[((int)(ty)&31)*32 + ((int)(tx)&31)+mp]*0.7;
  glColor3f(c/2.0,c/1.2,c/2.0);glPointSize(8);glBegin(GL_POINTS);glVertex2i(r*8+530,320-y);glEnd();
 }
```

My Code:

```
//Draws Floor And Ceiling Tiles
for(int y = (int)(lineO+lineH); y<HEIGHT; y++) {
    float dy = y - ((float)HEIGHT/2f), raFix = (float) Math.cos(ca);
    texX = px/2 + (float)Math.cos(ra)*(HEIGHT/2)*32/dy/raFix;
    texY = py/2 - (float)Math.sin(ra)*(HEIGHT/2)*32/dy/raFix;
    int mpF = mapF[(int)(texY/32.0)*mapX+(int)(texX/32.0)]*32*32;
    int mpC = mapC[(int)(texY/32.0)*mapX+(int)(texX/32.0)]*32*32;
                
    Color c = colors[textures[((int)(texY)&31)*32 + ((int)(texX)&31)+mpF]];
    g.setColor(getShade(c, ratio));
    g.drawLine(drawX, y, drawX, y);
                
    c = colors[textures[((int)(texY)&31)*32 + ((int)(texX)&31)+mpC]];
    g.setColor(getShade(c, ratio));
    g.drawLine(drawX, HEIGHT-y, drawX, HEIGHT-y);
}
```

Notes:

1. My engine makes use of "textures" through the use of an int array and gets the java.awt.Color object that corresponds to the value from the texture array within a java.awt.Color array
2. My engine does not make the use of x-planes, y-planes, or z-buffers like other ray casters do as the engine only needs the ray's hit position, the ray's angle, the player's position, and the distance between the player position and ray's position to properly calculate what it needs to draw on screen.
3. My engine uses three int arrays, the first being mapW, which represents the wall layouts and textures for the walls. The second being mapF, which is the floor textures for the walkable spaces. And the third being mapC which is the same in concept as the floor int array, but for the ceiling.
4. Any potential solutions need to allow me easy access to the value of the floor/ceiling tile that I am getting the texture from as doing so will allow me to later implement more complex lighting/shading techniques.
5. If it would be more helpful, here is the entire java file that I am doing the raycasting in:

```
package launcher;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import SwingUI.ComputerController;
import SwingUI.Program;
import world.Texture;

//This class extends a class I made in another Java Project, which I exported as a JAR file
//The class Program, is a JFrame subclass that implements the game loop

public class Game extends Program{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int mapX = 16, mapY = 16, mapS = 64, mapLen = mapX*mapY;
    private int door = 4;

    private int[] mapW = {
            1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2, //16
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1, 2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2, //32
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1, 2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2, //48
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,4, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2, //64
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1, 2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2, //80
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1, 2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2, //96
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1, 2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2, //112
            1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,4,2,2,2,2, //128

            1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 3,3,3,0,3,3,3,3, //144
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1, 3,0,0,0,0,0,0,3, //160
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1, 3,0,0,0,0,0,0,3, //176
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1, 3,0,0,0,0,0,0,3, //192
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 4,0,0,0,0,0,0,3, //208
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1, 3,0,0,0,0,0,0,3, //224
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1, 3,0,0,0,0,0,0,3, //240
            1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3, //256
    };

    private int[] mapF = {
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, //16
            0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, //32
            0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, //48
            0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, //64
            0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, //80
            0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, //96
            0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, //112
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, //128

            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0, //144
            0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, //160
            0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, //176
            0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, //192
            0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, //208
            0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, //224
            0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, //240
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, //256
    };

    private int[] mapC = {
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, //16
            0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, 0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, //32
            0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, 0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, //48
            0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, //64
            0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, 0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, //80
            0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, 0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, //96
            0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, 0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, //112
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, //128

            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0, //144
            0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, 0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, //160
            0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, 0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, //176
            0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, 0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, //192
            0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2, 0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, //208
            0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, 0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, //224
            0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, 0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0, //240
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, //256
    };

    private int[] textures = Texture.textures;
    private Color[] colors = Texture.colors;

    public Game(String title) {
        super(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setResizable(false);
        px = 100;
        py = 100;
    }

    float px,centX,py,centY,pdx,pdy,pa;
    float velX, velY;
    boolean forward,backward,left,right;
    boolean tl,tr;

    /**
     * Updates all game objects
     * In this case, it handles the camera
     */
    @Override
    public void updateObjects() {
        forward = ComputerController.keys[KeyEvent.VK_W];
        left = ComputerController.keys[KeyEvent.VK_A];
        backward = ComputerController.keys[KeyEvent.VK_S];
        right = ComputerController.keys[KeyEvent.VK_D];

        tl = ComputerController.keys[KeyEvent.VK_LEFT];
        tr = ComputerController.keys[KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT];

        if(tl)
            pa -= 0.05;
        if(tr)
            pa += 0.05;

        if(pa > PI2)
            pa -= PI2;
        if(pa < 0)
            pa += PI2;

        pdx = (float)Math.cos(pa)*5;
        pdy = (float)Math.sin(pa)*5;

        velX = 0;
        velY = 0;

        if(forward) {
            velX += pdx;
            velY += pdy;
        }
        else if(backward) {
            velX -= pdx;
            velY -= pdy;
        }

        if(left) {
            velX += pdy;
            velY -= pdx;
        }
        else if(right) {
            velX -= pdy;
            velY += pdx;
        }

        int mpx = (int)(centX/mapS), mpy = (int)(centY/mapS), mpxO = (int)((centX+velX)/mapS), mpyO = (int)((centY+velY)/mapS);
        if(mapW[mpy*mapX + mpxO] == 0)
            px+=velX;
        if(mapW[mpyO*mapX + mpx] == 0)
            py+=velY;

        if(ComputerController.keys[KeyEvent.VK_E]) {
            mpxO = (int)((centX+pdx*10)/mapS);
            mpyO = (int)((py+pdy*10)/mapS);
            if(mapW[mpyO*mapX + mpxO] == door)
                mapW[mpyO*mapX + mpxO] = 0;
        }

        centX = px+3;
        centY = py+3;
    }

    BasicStroke brushSize = new BasicStroke(16);
    BasicStroke reset = new BasicStroke(1);

    /**
     * Draws everything to the screen
     */
    @Override
    public void renderObjects(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setStroke(reset);
        g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        castRays(g2d);
    }

    int fov = 64, fineness=4, totalRays = (int) (fov*fineness*(16/brushSize.getLineWidth())), renderDistance = 8;
    float PI = (float) Math.PI, PI2 = (float) (2*Math.PI), PIHalf = (float) (Math.PI/2), PI3Half = (float) (3*Math.PI/2);
    float DR = (float) Math.toRadians(1), DROffset = (float) (Math.toRadians(1)/fineness), drawXOffset = brushSize.getLineWidth()/fineness;

    /**
     * Implements Raycasting rendering
     */
    private void castRays(Graphics2D g) {
        int r,mxH,myH,mxV,myV,mpH,mpV,dofH,dofV;
        float ra=fixAngle(pa-(DR*fov/2)),xo1=0,yo1=0, xo2=0,yo2=0;

        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));

        for(r=0; r < totalRays; r++) {
            dofH=0; dofV=0;
            float aTan = (float) (-1/Math.tan(ra)),  nTan = (float) -Math.tan(ra);
            float distH = 1000000000,hx=centX,hy=centY,distV = 1000000000,vx=centX,vy=centY;

            // Horizontal Line Check!!!!
            if(ra>PI) {hy = (float) (((int)centY/mapS)*mapS-0.0001); hx = (centY-hy)*aTan+centX; yo1 = -mapS; xo1 = -yo1*aTan;}
            else if(ra<PI) {hy = ((int)centY/mapS)*mapS+mapS; hx = (centY-hy)*aTan+centX; yo1 = mapS; xo1 = -yo1*aTan;}
            else if(ra==PI || ra==0) {hx=centX;hy=centY;dofH=8;}

            for(dofH=0; dofH < mapX; dofH++) {
                mxH=(int)hx/mapS; myH=(int)hy/mapS; mpH=myH*mapX+mxH;
                boolean withinMapH = hitWall(mpH);
                if(withinMapH) {distH=getDistance(hx,hy,centX,centY);dofH=mapX;}
                else {hx+=xo1;hy+=yo1;}
            }
            
            // Vertical Line Check!!!!
            if(ra>PIHalf&&ra<PI3Half) {vx = (float) (((int)centX/mapS)*mapS-0.0001); vy = (centX-vx)*nTan+centY; xo2 = -mapS; yo2 = -xo2*nTan;}
            else if(ra<PIHalf||ra>PI3Half) {vx = ((int)centX/mapS)*mapS+mapS; vy = (centX-vx)*nTan+centY; xo2 = mapS; yo2 = -xo2*nTan;}
            else if(ra==PI||ra==0) {vy=centX;vx=centY;dofV=8;}

            for(dofV=0; dofV < mapY; dofV++) {
                mxV=(int)vx/mapS; myV=(int)vy/mapS; mpV=myV*mapX+mxV;
                boolean withinMapV = hitWall(mpV);
                if(withinMapV) {distV=getDistance(vx,vy,centX,centY);dofV=mapY;}
                else {vx+=xo2;vy+=yo2;} 
            }

            //Get Shortest Distance
            float distT = 0, rx = 0, ry = 0;
            if(distH<distV) {distT=distH;rx=hx;ry=hy;}
            else if(distV<distH) {distT=distV;rx=vx;ry=vy;}
            
            //Fix Fish-eye effect
            float ca = fixAngle(pa-ra);
            distT*=Math.cos(ca);

            //Prepare for drawing Psuedo 3D Environment
            float lineH = (mapS*WIDTH)/distT;
            int drawX = r*(int)drawXOffset;

            float stepY=32/lineH;
            float texYOff=0;
            if(lineH > HEIGHT) {
                texYOff = (lineH-HEIGHT)/2;
                lineH = HEIGHT;
            }
            float lineO = HEIGHT/2-lineH/2;
            int mx=(int)rx/mapS, my=(int)ry/mapS, mp=my*mapX+mx, mt = mapW[mp]-1;
            float texY=texYOff*stepY+mt*32, texX=0;
            if(rx==vx) {
                texX=(int)(ry/2)%32;
                if(ra>PIHalf && ra<PI3Half) {texX = 31-texX;}
            }
            else {
                texX=(int)(rx/2)%32;
                if(ra<PI) {texX = 31-texX;}
            }
            
            //Draws Walls
            float ratio = distT/(mapS*renderDistance);
            for(int y = 0; y < (int)lineH; y++) {
                Color c = colors[textures[(int)texY*32+(int)texX]];
                g.setColor(getShade(c, ratio));
                g.drawLine(drawX, y+(int)(lineO), drawX, y+(int)(lineO));
                texY+=stepY;
            }
            
            
            //Draws Floor And Ceiling Tiles
            for(int y = (int)(lineO+lineH); y<HEIGHT; y++)
            {
                float dy = y - ((float)HEIGHT/2f), raFix = (float) Math.cos(ca);
                texX = px/2 + (float)Math.cos(ra)*(HEIGHT/2)*32/dy/raFix;
                texY = py/2 - (float)Math.sin(ra)*(HEIGHT/2)*32/dy/raFix;
                int mpF = mapF[(int)(texY/32.0)*mapX+(int)(texX/32.0)]*32*32;
                int mpC = mapC[(int)(texY/32.0)*mapX+(int)(texX/32.0)]*32*32;
                
                Color c = colors[textures[((int)(texY)&31)*32 + ((int)(texX)&31)+mpF]];
                g.setColor(c);
                g.drawLine(drawX, y, drawX, y);
                
                c = colors[textures[((int)(texY)&31)*32 + ((int)(texX)&31)+mpC]];
                g.setColor(c);
                g.drawLine(drawX, HEIGHT-y, drawX, HEIGHT-y);
            }

            //Get Next Angle
            ra = fixAngle(ra+DROffset);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Detects if a ray has hit a wall
     * @param mp
     *  The world-position of the ray's end point
     * @return
     *  True if the position is within bounds and is a wall tile
     */
    public boolean hitWall(int mp) {
        return (mp >= 0 && mp < mapLen && mapW[mp] > 0);
    }

    /**
     * Resets angles to the correct value if they are above 2PI radians (360 degrees) or below 0 radians (0 degrees)
     *  @param angle
     *   The angle we are fixing
     *  @return
     *   The fixed angle
     */
    public float fixAngle(float angle) {
        if(angle > PI2) {
            angle -= PI2;
        }
        if(angle < 0) {
            angle += PI2;
        }
        return angle;
    }

    
    /**
     * 
     * Gets the distance between two points
     * @param ax 
     *  the X Coordinate of the first point
     * @param ay
     *  the Y Coordinate of the first point
     * 
     * @param bx 
     *  the X Coordinate of the second point
     * @param by
     *  the Y Coordinate of the second point
     * @return
     *  The distance between the two points
     */
    public float getDistance(float ax, float ay, float bx, float by) {
        return (float)Math.sqrt( (bx-ax)*(bx-ax) + (by-ay)*(by-ay) );
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Gets a shade of a given color relative to the ratio given
     * @param color
     *  The color we want to change
     * @param ratio
     *  What percent it is close to the color black
     * @return
     *  The new shade
     */
    private Color getShade(Color color, float ratio){
        int r = (int) Math.round(Math.max(0, color.getRed() - 255 * ratio));
        int g = (int) Math.round(Math.max(0, color.getGreen() - 255 * ratio));
        int b = (int) Math.round(Math.max(0, color.getBlue() - 255 * ratio));

        int rgb = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
        return new Color(rgb);
    }
    
    /**
     * Creates GUI on launch
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game("RAYCASTER");
    }
}
```

6. The fixAngle method resets angles to the correct value if they are above 2PI radians (360 degrees) or below 0 radians (0 degrees). For example, an angle of 5PI/2 would return PI/2, and an angle of -3PI/2 would return PI/2
7. The getShade method returns a shade of a given color relative to the ratio given. The ratio is what percent (in decimal form) the desired color is close to the color black

Comment: read carefully the Exception message then you could see the problem: -11 cannot be an index of an array. Meaning your calculation returns a neg. value. If it returns a number that is larger than the number of array elements you get also an IndexOutOfBoundException.

Comment: I understand that, however, I am using what is functionally the same formula for the floor casting as what the tutorial uses but I am getting values that cause indexOutOfBounds exceptions and I can't seem to figure out why it is doing so

Comment: You shouldn't blindly copy things that won't work, but study the algorithm and correct or amend it.

Comment: The whole point of this question WAS to get help in understanding how the algorithm work and what I was doing wrong, as I can not find other resources that use the same method that the creator used. All the other resources online use lodev's or permadi's version of raycasting which includes x/y planes, and z-buffers, both of which, as stated in my question, I do not have and can not implement as they don't fit the engine that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be a bit more helpful about answering your question. I recently had the same problem and was coincidentally working from the same tutorial as you were. I ran into the same problem as you and it took me 3 days to figure out the solution. I apologize for not understanding the maths behind it, as I am still in high school and I have not taken triginometry. However, after trial and error, I have found a solution. I really hope that this helps you with your project and good luck with future projects!

```
for (int y=(int)(lineO+lineH); y<height; y++)
{
  //------------------------draw floor------------------------\\
  float dy=y-(320/2.0), raFix=cos(ca);
  tx=px/2 + cos(ra)*158*32/dy/raFix;
  ty=py/2 + sin(ra)*158*32/dy/raFix;
  int MP=mapF[(int)(ty/32.0)*mapX+(int)(tx/32.0)]*32*32;
  float c=All_Textures[((int)(ty)&31)*32 + ((int)(tx)&31)+MP]*0.7;
  fill(c/1.3*255, c/1.3*255, c*255);//code to change the color of the boxes
  rect(r*8+530, y, 8, 8);//code to draw the boxes

  //------------------------draw ceiling------------------------\\
  mp=mapC[(int)(ty/32.0)*mapX+(int)(tx/32.0)]*32*32;
  c=All_Textures[((int)(ty)&31)*32 + ((int)(tx)&31)+mp]*0.7;
  fill(c/2.0*255, c/1.2*255, c/2.0*255); //code to change the color of the boxes
  rect(r*8+530, 320-y, 8, 8); //code to draw the boxes
}
```